# Tour of PPCG: Voting Phase

Tags: discussion

As described in [my last meta post](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9092/20198), the purpose of this post is to nominate and vote on posts that deserve more visibility.

The criterion for voting and nomination include 4 aspects:  **Quality, difficulty, acceptability, and visibility**.

1. **Quality:**  The post should be well written, and on-topic under our current guidelines.  Furthermore, the challenge should avoid practices that we are trying to move away from (such as arbitrary language restrictions, difficult I/O models, or pop-cons that don't need to be pop-cons)
2. **Difficulty:**  Avoid the extremes:  Extremely difficult challenges may cause users to give up, and too many easy challenges makes completing the Tour less of an accomplishment.
3. **Acceptability of new answers:**  Some problematic challenges include:

   1. Challenges that are closed to new answers (most [fastest-code](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fastest-code) and [king-of-the-hill](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/king-of-the-hill))
   2. Challenges that don't work with a large amount of answers (most [answer-chaining](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/answer-chaining))
   3. Challenges with little room for new, distinct answers (such as ["Hello, World!"](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/55422/hello-world))
4. **Visibility:** We are actually looking for *lesser-known* questions here.  While our [2014](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/17005/produce-the-number-2014-without-any-numbers-in-your-source-code) challenge may still be unseen by some of our newest users, we're hoping to introduce challenges to as many users as possible.  The *age* of a challenge matters as well, but not as much as the *popularity* of the challenge.

Remember, all of the above are *relative* criterion.  The question doesn't have to be the ideal in all of the aspects, but a terrible question won't make the top 25.

**Please include the tags of the question in your post so that we are able to easily choose a wide variety of questions**

Comment: I don't have a suggestion, but since the name clashes somewhat with the help tour, perhaps someone else could think of something catchy and meaningful?

Comment: Name suggestion: Community Picks

Comment: Name suggestion: Most Significant Bits.

Comment: "The age of a challenge matters as well": are older challenges more or less desirable?

Comment: @Zgarb More desirable, but only on the basis that they are lesser-known.  Many of our older questions are off-topic, and shouldn't be considered.

Comment: Name suggestion (if we only end up with golfing challenges): The Golf Course.

Answer (score 14):

### [Squarefinder - Locating regular tetragons](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/42394/squarefinder-locating-regular-tetragons)

[code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf) [geometry](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/geometry)

Pros:

- Less than 600 views as of writing this.
- Only 3 answers so far, but all use totally different approaches.
- A good spec with pictures, easy to understand.

Cons:

- Somewhat difficult.

Comment: Oooh, I really like this one.  +1 for difficulty.

Comment: I would have to agree, this question provided me lots of hours of fun and I am sure there are better answers out there.

Answer (score 9):

### [ASCII Art of the Day #1 - Double Knot](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/50484/ascii-art-of-the-day-1-double-knot)

[code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf)[ascii-art](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ascii-art)[kolmogorov-complexity](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/kolmogorov-complexity)

Pros:

- It has a solid spec
- It's part of a series, so users that enjoy the challenge will be able to find more like it

Cons:

- It's newerish (Posted almost exactly a year ago)
- It doesn't have a large scope of possible answers

Trivia: The top answer outgolfs Dennis

Comment: `the top answer outgolfs Dennis` totally important, can't discourage newer users. :P

Answer (score 6):

### [Lattice Points inside a circle](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/1938/code-golf-lattice-points-inside-a-circle?rq=1)

[code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf)[geometry](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/geometry)

Pros:

- Is *old*.  This beauty is from 2011
- Despite its age, actually has a pretty solid spec
- Very few answers

Cons:

- I'm unsure how many techniques can be used to calculate, so answers may start to overlap

Answer (score 5):

### [Calculate practical numbers](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/24258/calculate-practical-numbers)

[code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf) [sequence](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sequence) [number-theory](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/number-theory)

Pros:

- Short and easy-to-understand spec.
- Only 4 answers, top answer is "not really golfed".
- Over 2 years old.

Cons:

- The time limit makes it more difficult.

Comment: I think a question where the answers show that scoring is usually in "bytes" not "chars" would be better.

Comment: @mbomb007, that would rule out 99% of old questions, which is rather missing the point.

Comment: @PeterTaylor Then perhaps the tour/help page should include a description of the usual proper answer format, so that new users don't pick up the bad habits of the past.

Comment: I think we can safely edit the scoring to be bytes *as long as* it doesn't change the score for any of the answers.

Answer (score 4):

### [Generate Skolem sequences](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/11861/generate-skolem-sequences)

[code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf) [math](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/math) [sequence](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sequence)

Pros:

- It's from June 2013, so almost 3 years old, and has less than 700 views.
- Not too hard, but not trivial either, and there are probably many different approaches.
- The spec is short and simple (ignoring the weird background story).

Comment: I *do* like the problem, but I'm not a huge fan of the spec.  Maybe we clean it up?

Comment: @NathanMerrill I edited the spec to better fit our standards.

Comment: Ooh, this is *much* better.

Answer (score 4):

Since the question of mine that was nominated here was received so poorly, allow me to nominate one of my own:

## [Build a Flood Paint AI](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/26232/create-a-flood-paint-ai/26313#26313)

[code-challenge](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-challenge) [test-battery](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/test-battery)

Pros:

- It's relatively old (from 2014).
- It's only got about 3,000 views so far, even with 27 upvotes.
- It has a very granular scoring criterion, with 7-digit scores sometimes varying by as little as a few hundred.
- **The optimal solution is still unknown.** (In fact, this particular problem is [NP-hard](http://www.bris.ac.uk/news/2010/6945.html).)
- It's relatively easy, but not trivial, to write a solution for and prove that it works.
- There's lots of different, creative approaches that can be taken to solve this problem.
- No loophole abuse; because the challenge is algorithmic in nature, there's not really a flaw in the spec that can be exploited to produce a trivial good-scoring answer.
- No esolang abuse; because the challenge is algorithmic in nature, golfing languages do not have a natural advantage in producing better-scoring answers than long-form languages.

Cons:

- It requires a large input file, which is mirrored on a third-party website.
- There are a bunch of existing solutions (although the last time anyone actually posted a new answer was May 2014, two years ago).
- It has one of my famous "last-place reference solutions", which is something I do with a lot of my code-challenge questions that was recently declared as frowned upon.

  The answer for this problem in particular, however, requires a bit of proof to show that it's actually valid, so I think it can stay there. It also acts as a bare-minimum guideline — if your solution is not at least as good as this one, it shouldn't be submitted, because there's something wrong with it.

Comment: Also, this seems to be the only non-code-golf question being presented. Nobody has any other code challenges?

Comment: Nope, other scoring methods are allowed.  However, there are a couple of other scoring methods ([tag:fastest-code], [tag:cops-and-robbers], [tag:king-of-the-hill]) that don't work too well, which is why the majority of the answers are [tag:code-golf]

Comment: That said, I'd recommend splitting up the two problems into two different posts (so we can talk/vote on them seperately)

Comment: Alright, done. http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/9182/7110

Answer (score 3):

### [Reverse Indentation](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/42510/reverse-indentation)

[code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf)[string](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/string)[whitespace](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/whitespace)

Pros:

- Written in 2014 (barely)
- Has a humorous, interesting spec
- Is easy to understand, but has lots of approaches
- As of this writing, only has 10 answers
- Teaches the importance of Java scripting

Cons:

Answer (score 3):

### [Lego gear ratios](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/7143/lego-gear-ratios)

[code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf) [math](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/math)

Pros:

- Simple, concrete and fun spec.
- Old, from September 2012.
- There seems to be room for more answers.

Cons:

- The I/O formats are strict (but not *too* annoying).

Answer (score 3):

Here's also another test-battery question for your consideration:

## [Build a minimum-clue Sudoku unsolver](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/48509/build-a-minimum-clue-sudoku-unsolver)

[code-challenge](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-challenge) [test-battery](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/test-battery)

Pros:

- It's only got about 600 views so far, even with 11 upvotes.
- It's only got 3 answers right now, so the solution space is largely unexplored as of now.
- It has a very granular scoring criterion, with 7-digit scores sometimes varying by as little as a few hundred.
- **The optimal solution is still unknown.**
- There's lots of different, creative approaches that can be taken to solve this problem.
- No loophole abuse; because the challenge is algorithmic in nature, there's not really a flaw in the spec that can be exploited to produce a trivial good-scoring answer.
- No esolang abuse; because the challenge is algorithmic in nature, golfing languages do not have a natural advantage in producing better-scoring answers than long-form languages.

Cons:

- It requires a large input file, which is mirrored on a third-party website.
- It's a bit harder than the Flood Paint problem to prove that a solution will work.
- It has a last-place reference solution just like the Flood Paint one. This one isn't quite as novel though, so I can remove it if desired.

Comment: I don't like "with shorter code breaking a tie" in a code challenge, but +1 anyway it's a really interesting challenge.

Comment: @trichoplax The "shorter code breaking a tie" is a catch-all in the rare case that two solutions have exactly the same score, which has happened with the Flood Paint question.

Comment: I understand that - I just much prefer "first posted" as a tie breaker, so there is a single objective rather than also golfing. There's more in [this meta answer](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/8195/20283) (plus the opportunity to vote...).

Answer (score 1):

### [Word Search Puzzle](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/37940/word-search-puzzle?rq=1)

[code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf)[string](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/string)[word-search](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/word-search)

Pros:

1. Common problem that is quickly understood
2. Doesn't require a dictionary
3. Low chance of solution overlap
4. The accepted answer has a *great* explanation

Cons:

1. May be a bit too easy

Comment: If you want a slightly harder version, I've got a similar question from 2011: http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/3383/wordsearch-solver

Comment: (With apologies if it's a bit egotistical to propose one of your own questions for this :-)

Comment: @Gareth post it, and let us vote on it :)

Answer (score 1):

### [Solve an 0h n0 board](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/70290/solve-an-0h-n0-board)

[code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf) [puzzle-solver](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/puzzle-solver)

#### Pros

- Low view count (~450)
- Only one answer
- Fairly easy to understand (At least in my opinion, correct me if I'm wrong)

#### Cons

- Quite difficult (I haven't even figured out where to start solving it :)
- Fairly new (~2.5 months old)

Answer (score 1):

## [Tiling Given Vertex Configuration](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/41439/tiling-given-vertex-configuration)

[code-challenge](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-challenge) [graphical-output](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/graphical-output) [geometry](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/geometry) [tiling](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tiling)

- Has several levels of complexity (beginners are able to start easy)
- Very few answers

Answer (score 0):

### [The Floating Horde](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/23631/the-floating-horde/23657#23657)

[code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf) [probably-needs-another-tag](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/probably-needs-another-tag)

Pros:

- Great theme
- Part of a series, introducing users to other questions
- 2 years old

Cons:

- It was pretty popular back in the day

Comment: The I/O requirements are needlessly restrictive from a modern view. Not sure what you can do about that.

Comment: I'm not sure what you are considering "restrictive".  It allows input via STDIN, arguments, or from a file.  That pretty much covers most of the bases.

Comment: I meant that the list has to be input and output as a space-separate string. At least, the existing are doing that processing.

Answer (score 0):

## [Self-Shortening Prime Tester](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/47923/self-shortening-prime-tester?rq=1)

[code-challenge](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-challenge)[quine](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/quine)[primes](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/primes)[code-generation](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-generation)

Pros:

- Straightforward challenge
- Introduces users to quines
- Low amount of votes/answers

Cons:

- The "sub challenge" (prime checking) is pretty simple, so we *may* end up with duplicate entries

Answer (score -1):

## [Decimal Multiplication of Strings](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/71427/decimal-multiplication-of-strings)

[code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf)[string](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/string)

Pros:

- It has a solid spec

Cons:

- It's newerish (Posted a couple months ago)
- It doesn't have *too much* of a large scope of possible answers. Not that bad though.

Answer (score -1):

## [Lossy ASCII art compression](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/53199/lossy-ascii-art-compression)

[code-challenge](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-challenge) [ascii-art](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ascii-art) [compression](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/compression)

**Quality:** Unambiguous spec, script to verify and score outputs, objective validity criterion and scoring.

**Difficulty:** Challenging enough to be interesting, but naive approaches are possible because the required compression quality is a lower limit, not a strict target, allowing a range of solutions gradually getting nearer to optimal. Optimal is likely unattainable, so the challenge is open ended. This has a nice balance of easy to enter and difficult to win.

**Acceptability of new answers:** Does not require challenge author's involvement to score new solutions. No upper limit on number of solutions. A wide variety of approaches is likely to be possible.

**Visibility:** Posted July 2015. No answers yet. 12 upvotes and 597 views. An intriguing but accessible challenge that seems to have flown under the radar.

Comment: It *is* well defined, but it took me several reads to comprehend what "lossy" meant for this challenge.  Also, does the verification script *really* have to be in CJam?

Comment: I agree. CJam isn't a good choice for a verification script.

Comment: Would this be better accepted if someone wrote a verification script in python or as a Stack Snippet?

Answer (score -3):

### [Print every character your program doesn't have](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/12368/print-every-character-your-program-doesnt-have)

[code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf)

Pros:

- It's from 2013, so it's fairly old in terms of challenges.
- The newest solution was posted [over two years ago](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/19717/45941).
- It's one of our [highest voted questions](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions?sort=votes).
- It's a reasonably simple challenge that leads to interesting solutions.

Cons:

- It has a lot of solutions in many different languages already, so the potential for duplicate solutions is high.
- Though it isn't as popular now, it was extremely popular when it was posted, so it may not be a great fit for the "lesser-known" criteria.
- There's a lot of abuse of loopholes that later became standard forbidden loopholes in the existing answers.

Comment: While there are a lot of submissions already, its quite easy to come up with alternate solutions due to the nature of the challenge.

Comment: It's rather unfortunate, though, that the top voted answer is nowhere near competitive and that the second top voted answer is a standard loophole.

Comment: I don't conside that question one of PPCG's best. I think it's actually think it's one of our lower quality questions, and raising it up may introduce a return of poorly formatted questions. It allowed what was already a known loophole and had answers that were voted up despite it. I had to take a short hiatus from here after that, but I'm glad to see how far this community has come with its rules and standards.

Comment: @miles The challenge would be much improved if solutions which violate loopholes were removed, even if they predate the loophole being banned. The spec itself is fine. But, alas, I am in the minority in that debate.

Comment: I come across this thread to find that the one question on this list written by me is also the lowest voted candidate. Are my puzzles that bad? :(

Comment: @JoeZ. I like the challenge. I think the downvotes are because of the rampant loophole abuse in the solutions (which was not your fault; it's because the standard loopholes weren't banned back then, and people don't want to retroactively apply those bans to existing answers for some reason).